# How to return any* type from postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, polymorphism

I can `returns setof record` and provide definition list to get result:

```
select (f.row).* from tree( 'resource_type' ) f( id int, path int[], fullname text, level int, row resource_type );
```

But how to rewrite my function to return `any` type with automatic cast?

This does not work:

```sql
create or replace function tree( _tbl regclass )
--returns setof record
returns table( id int, path int[], fullname text, level int, r record )
as $$
BEGIN
return query execute format( '
WITH RECURSIVE parent ( id, path, fullname, level, row ) AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      ARRAY[ id ],
      ''/'' || name::text,
      1,
      %1$s
    FROM %1$s
    WHERE parent_id = 13
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      child.id,
      parent.path || child.id,
      parent.fullname || ''/'' || child.name,
      parent.level +1,
      child
    FROM parent
    JOIN %1$s child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
    WHERE NOT child.id = ANY(path)
)
SELECT * FROM parent ', _tbl);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

```
=> select f.r from tree( 'resource_type' ) f
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type resource_type does not match expected type record in column 5.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function tree(regclass) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to write a polymorphic function is to use `anyelement`. But you *must* provide an argument of type `anyelement` as well. The actual data type will then be deduced from the type of that argument:

```
CREATE FUNCTION poly(
   outtype anyelement,
   otherparam integer
) RETURNS TABLE (res anyelement)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   resulttype regtype := pg_typeof(outtype);
   whetever text;
BEGIN
   /* calculate a text representation of the result in "whatever" */
   EXECUTE format('SELECT CAST ($1 AS %s)', resulttype)
      USING whatever INTO res;
   RETURN NEXT;
END;$$
```

You call a function like this by supplying a dummy argument of the desired type:

```
SELECT * FROM poly(NULL::myresulttype, 42);
```

Comment: Seems CASTing is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass `anyelement` as argument, then I can use `anyelement` for `returns ...` statement. [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC)

```
create or replace function tree( _tbl anyelement )
returns table( id int, path int[], fullname text, level int, "row" anyelement )
as $$
BEGIN
return query execute format( '...', pg_typeof( _tbl )::text );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```